# Changing window size uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, window

I'm building a simple game for a project in school.
I want to set the aspect ratio of the screen to be 16:9;
i have wrote those lines:

```
mainpage.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
mainpage.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 0.5625;
```

in the `SizeChanged` event, but the result is this

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/VcrCz.png]

does anyone know how to change the window size itself?

```
<Page Name="mainpage"
    x:Class="CTT.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CTT"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded" SizeChanged="Page_SizeChanged" >
```

those are the first lines of the xaml code

Comment: you should change window size not page

Comment: I realiaze that but i cant figure iot a way to do so, do you know how ?

Comment: Yea but it only works for the launch. I want it to be active when the code is running so if someone changes the window size in mid-game than the window will keep a fixed aspet ratio

Comment: You could try to use `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(desiredSize)` to  change the size of the view. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview#Methods